# Inconsistent drawing in Pygame on Mac OSX Mojave

Tags: python, macos, pygame, macos-mojave

I've been making a Pokemon-style game on and off for a month or so, and just recently updated to Mojave to check out the new features.

After updating, I noticed a few minor issues with my game, one specific issue being an HP Bar that doesn't draw the way it used to with High Sierra. Before it would gradually decrease in width, but now the program just freezes for the amount of time the animation would play, and then skips to the end of the animation. Why might this occur?

I know by now that Pygame has drawing issues with Mojave (supposedly due to the new Dark Mode), but I've yet to see anyone describe a situation in which only a *small part* of their program has been affected- most reports are from '18 and complain about a *complete lack of drawing whatsoever*.

Anyway, here's my code for the HP Bar animation:

```
def changeHP(barPos, maxHP, startHP, dif): #This function displays the animation for hp loss/gain
    timer = pygame.time.Clock()
    for i in range(int(dif*100/maxHP)):
        difPer = (maxHP*i/100)
        if startHP - difPer <= maxHP/5:
            color = Color(255, 0, 0, 255)
        elif startHP - difPer <= maxHP/2:
            color = Color(255, 255, 0, 255)
        else:
            color = Color(0, 255, 0, 255)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, Color(255, 255, 255, 255), (barPos[0], barPos[1], 144, 9))
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, (barPos[0], barPos[1], ((startHP - difPer)/maxHP) * 144, 9))
        pygame.display.update()
        timer.tick(60)
```

Sorry if some of the values seem convoluted, it's a work in progress.

Comment: Do you call `pygame.display.update()` and/or `timer.tick()` from multiple places?  Maybe there's some sort of display-update syncopation going on - the update is happening, but "flushes" are running too-close together to see it on-screen??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh, I didn't think this would actually work, but it did.

I added an event queue check to the loop, and everything went back to normal.

Here's my updated code:

```
def changeHP(barPos, maxHP, startHP, dif): #This function displays the animation for hp loss/gain
timer = pygame.time.Clock()
for i in range(int(dif*100/maxHP)):
    difPer = (maxHP*i/100)
    if startHP - difPer <= maxHP/5:
        color = Color(255, 0, 0, 255)
    elif startHP - difPer <= maxHP/2:
        color = Color(255, 255, 0, 255)
    else:
        color = Color(0, 255, 0, 255)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, Color(255, 255, 255, 255), (barPos[0], barPos[1], 144, 9))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, (barPos[0], barPos[1], ((startHP - difPer)/maxHP) * 144, 9))
    pygame.display.update()
    timer.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```